# How to marshal array of bools in C++ to an array of bool in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have the following COM visible property in a C# class:

```
[ComVisible]
bool[] Values;
```

I have an instance of the class in C++ and used the following code to set this property (only pseudocode)

```
CComSafeArray<VARIANT_BOOL> values(3);
values[0] = VARIANT_FALSE;
values[1] = VARIANT_FALSE;

HRESULT hr = instance->put_Values(values.Detach());
```

The last line of the above code returns COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH (0x80131533). I tried with BYTE and VARIANT (with BOOL), but no success.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to figure it out but I got it: pass VT_BOOL as the second template parameter to CComSafeArray:

```
CComSafeArray<VARIANT_BOOL, VT_BOOL> values(3);
```

Without that template parameter, the SAFEARRAY will be created with the VARTYPE VT_I2 (a 2-byte integer, because VARIANT_BOOL is an alias for **short**), which is not what a C# property of type **bool[]** expects.